# JavaFX rendering bug with too many ImageViews on screen

Tags: javafx, imageview

I'm working on a game with JavaFX, and I'm bumping into graphics rendering issues if there are too many entities/ImageViews on the screen.

I'm using a Group as the root node of the scene, where I add an ImageView for each entity; to update the entities' positions, I use the methods setTranslateX and setTranslateY for each ImageView and for a ParallelCamera that keeps the main character centered on the screen. When the main character is not moving (aka the ParallelCamera is stationary) and there are several ImageViews on the screen, the view is not updated as it should.

Can I fix this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: How many are "too many"?

Comment: I think about 40 ImageView

Comment: 40 ImageViews is not much. This should work if the images are reasonably sized.